# mvc3 view cannot load namespace(How do views reference dlls)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, namespaces

I updated the dll references in my mvc3 site. they are the same dlls but different versions. I did this by first deleting them, then added the updated ones. All compiles properly. However at runtime, I get runtime errors of cshtml files not being able to reference some namespaces. When I open these cshtml files, the vs2010 does show an error of undefined namespaces. BUT the same namespaces work fine in codebehind cs files. In the respective view web.config file. I have tried:

```
  <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="myassembly" />
      </namespaces>

or 
      <controls>
        <add assembly="myassembly, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="myassembly" tagPrefix="myassembly" />
      </controls>
```

I still can't rectify the problem in my view. When I revert to old dlls version, EVERYTHING works fine and I don't need modification in view web.config. It seems like its a case of the view still trying to reference the old dll version, hence it can't find them when I update to new versions.

How do views reference dlls?

Thanks

Comment: did you try cleaning your solution or rebuilding it?

Comment: yes, i cleaned and rebuilt after every change, religiously.

Comment: I find that if I specify <reference include="myassembly" version=3.0.0.0><Private>True</Private></reference> in my .csprog file of my project. Clean, rebuild solution. Solves Problem.

Comment: I guess the csproj file wasn't saved after you updated the assembly. Good to know it got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the web.config file that is inside the Views folder, not the one that is in the root directory of your project.